# Removing all extension of a string in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've got dictionaries such as:

```
'1' : ['GAA', 'GAAA', 'GAAAA', 'GAAAAA', 'GAAAAAG', 'GAAAAAGU', 'GAAAAAGUA', 'GAAAAAGUAU', 'GAAAAAGUAUG', 'GAAAAAGUAUGC', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAG', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGAA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGAAC']

'2' : ['GAG', 'GAGA', 'GAGAG', 'GAGAGA', 'GAGAGAG', 'GAGAGAGA', 'GAGAGAGAC', 'GAGAGAGACA', 'GAGAGAGACAU', 'GAGAGAGACAUA', 'GAGAGAGACAUAG', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGA', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGAG', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGAGG']

'3' : ['GUC', 'GUCU', 'GUCUU', 'GUCUUU', 'GUCUUUG', 'GUCUUUGU', 'GUCUUUGU"', 'GUCUUUGU"G', 'GUCUUUGU"GU', 'GUCUUUGU"GUA', 'GUCUUUGU"GUAC', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACA', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACAU', 'GUCUUUGU"GUACAUC']
```

I am trying to make it so that the program can find the shortest substring in the list (such as GAA in the first) and use it to find all other entries that are simply extensions of GAA (strings that start with GAA and just have extra letters) and removes them.

I know there's been plenty of questions asked here about how to remove items from list, but none help me out in regards to this problem.

Comment: Using Regex would be a better approach.

Comment: how would regex help me @ZdaR? Sorry. I'm trying to automate all of this, so telling it to each list 1,2,3 to use different strings "GAA", "GAG", "GUC" is not  really an option for me

Comment: Don't hardcode the Regular Expression, instead create a Regex on the fly with the first element of the list.

Comment: I don't know if I'm the only one who noticed it, but every element on every list starts with the first element of the list...!!...First list, every element starts with `GAA`, same for second list, all starts with `GAG`...etc

Comment: This is only a small snippet of the lists though @IronFist. The full list restarts and has other 3 letter strings that are than extended with other letters.

Comment: ok...It would be better if you include them to be more general...

Comment: The problem is the actual dictionary with the list is generated in the program using a FASTA file so the lists contain thousands of substrings like that

Comment: if you have others with same minimum length (3), then you will not remove all of them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> dictionary={ '1': ['GAA', 'GAAA', 'GAAAA', 'GAAAAA', 'GAAAAAG', 'GAAAAAGU',
                    'GAAAAAGUA', 'GAAAAAGUAU', 'GAAAAAGUAUG', 'GAAAAAGUAUGC', 
                    'GAAAAAGUAUGCA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAG', 
                    'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGAA', 'GAAAAAGUAUGCAAGAAC', 
                    'RTRSRS','GAG', 'GAGA', 'GAGAG', 'GAGAGA', 'GAGAGAG', 'GAGAGAGA',
                  'GAGAGAGAC', 'GAGAGAGACA', 'GAGAGAGACAU', 'GAGAGAGACAUA', 
                  'GAGAGAGACAUAG', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGA', 'GAGAGAGACAUAGAG',
                  'GAGAGAGACAUAGAGG']}
>>> new_dict = {}

>>> for i in dictionary:
        l = len(min(dictionary[i], key=len))
        m = [x for x in dictionary[i] if len(x)==l]
        temp = []
        temp.extend(m)
        for k in dictionary[i]:
            if not any(map(lambda j: k.startswith(j), m)):
                temp.append(k)
        new_dict[i] = temp

>>> print(new_dict)
# {'1': ['GAA', 'GAG', 'RTRSRS']}
```

Comment: Thanks I mended this into my code so it did its job right, but it seems to have removed around 1,000 substrings, but there are still thousands more left that were not removed. Is this due to there being multiple 3 letter strings that are elongated by other letters and not just one "GAA" in list 1?

Comment: Aaah! i know I'm asking for a lot, but how would I go about making it use multiple instead of 1?

Comment: @lamazibiji check out this one, if it still fails, can you give an example output?

Comment: @Ayush-shakner it still fails. on list's result is: `['"', 'UGG', 'UGGU', 'UGGUA', 'UGGUAC', 'UGGUACU', 'UGGUACUU', 'UGGUACUU"', 'UGGUACUU"G', 'UGGUACUU"GU', 'UGGUACUU"GUU', 'UGGUACUU"GUUU', 'GG', 'GGU', 'GGUA', 'GGUAC', 'GGUACU', 'GGUACUU', 'GGUACUU"', 'GGUACUU"G', 'GGUACUU"GU'`   As you can see there are still leftovers where it's not getting rid of everything

Comment: @lamazibiji i've corrected my code to include multiple keys

Answer (score 2):

Your sample data is not really good. All other entries start with the shortest string. Hence, all would be removed. Here a shorter version with a different entry:

```
data = {'1' : ['GAA', 'xxxxxxx', 'GAAA', 'GAAAA', 'GAAAAA'],
        '2' : ['GAG', 'yyyyyyyy', 'GAGA', 'GAGAG', 'GAGAGA'],
        '3' : ['GUC', 'zzzzzz', 'GUCU', 'GUCUU', 'GUCUUU']}
```

Now:

```
res = {}
for key, value in data.items():
    shortest = min(value, key=len)
    res[key] = [entry for entry in value if not entry.startswith(shortest) 
                or entry == shortest]

>>> res
{'1': ['GAA', 'xxxxxxx'], '2': ['GAG', 'yyyyyyyy'], '3': ['GUC', 'zzzzzz']}
```

Note: This also keeps the position of the shortest string relative to the others that remain. Just in case this matters.